# Missing pieces of code in download local time

Tags: java, android, arraylist, time, localtime

I try to make ArrayList with local time. I would like to add local time to ArrayList always when i press the button.

Is it possible to make this from my code ?
Currenlty i can programme only this, and dont know how to complete this. :

```
public ArrayList<???> myTime = new ArrayList<???>();

       time.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
              myTime.add(???);  ;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you want:

```
public List<LocalTime> myTime = new ArrayList<> ();

//...

myTime.add(LocalTime.now());
```

Comment: android studio says: create class / enum / inner class / interface - with LocalTime so i think it's not work

Comment: @patrick1980 you didn't say you were on Android - LocalTime is a class available in Java 8.

Comment: i forgot about android, but i using jdk 1.8 so this should works